# Function won't work when using a list created from a file

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to create a list of words from a file is being read as then delete all words that contain duplicate letters. I was able to do it successfully with a list of words that I entered however when I try to use the function on the list created from a file the function still includes words with duplicates.

This works:

```
words = ['word','worrd','worrrrd','wordd']
alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
x = 0
while x in range(0, len(alpha)):
    i = 0
    while i in range(0, len(words)):
        if words[i].count(alpha[x]) > 1:
            del(words[i])
            i = i - 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
print(words)
```

This is how I'm trying to do it when reading the file:

```
words = []
length = 5
file = open('dictionary.txt')
for word in file:
    if len(word) == length+1:
        words.append(word.splitlines())

alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
x = 0
while x in range(0, len(alpha)):
    i = 0
    while i in range(0, len(words)):
        if words[i].count(alpha[x]) > 1:
            del(words[i])
            i = i - 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
print(words)
```

Comment: How do you define duplicate letters? Should 'level' be deleted or included?

Comment: @AustinHastings yes level will be deleted, ANY word where any letter repeats more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. First, the `string` module is not quite deprecated, but it's unpopular. Lucky for you, it defines some useful constants to save you a bunch of typing. So you don't have to type all those quotes and commas.

Next, use the `with open('filespec') as ...` **context** for reading files: it's what it was put there for!

Finally, be aware of how iteration works for text files: `for line in file:` reads *lines,* including any trailing newlines. Strip those off. If you don't have one-word-per-line, you'll have to split the lines after you read them.

```
# Read words (possibly >1 per line) from dictionary.txt into lexicon[].
# Convert the words to lower case.

import string

Lexicon = []

with open('dictionary.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.strip().lower().split()
        Lexicon.extend(words)


for ch in string.ascii_lowercase:
    for i in range(len(Lexicon)):
        word = Lexicon[i]

        if word.count(ch) > 1:
            del Lexicon[i]
            i -= 1

print('\n'.join(Lexicon))
```

Comment: is there any way i can use what ive got now but just adjust it because i dont want to change that approach i am using.

Comment: @EllisRourke, your approach makes over 400 calls when I profile it, mine makes about 18, and Dmitry's around 31. You should consider making it as efficient as possible considering the input size seems rather large in the file reading context.

Comment: The `with` | `as` syntax should def. be used in your file reading case

Comment: @JacobIRR i understand however it is for an introductory python course and is trying too keep syntax as simple as possible. Is there any way to fix the code i currently have?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#This more comprehensive sample allows me to reproduce the file-reading
#  problem in the script itself (before I changed the code "tee" would 
#  print,  for instance)
words = ['green','word','glass','worrd','door','tee','wordd']
outlist = []

for word in words:
    chars = [c for c in word]
    # a `set` only contains unique characters, so if it is shorter than the
    #  `word` itself, we found a word with duplicate characters, so we keep 
    #  looping
    if len(set(chars)) < len(chars):
        continue
    else:
        outlist.append(word)
print(outlist)
```

Result:

```
['word']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

words = ['word','worrd','worrrrd','wordd','5word']

new_words = [x for x in words if len(x) == len(set(x)) if all(i in string.ascii_letters for i in x)]

print(new_words)
```